# URI encoding for SQL column names in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-logic-apps

I have a number of Logic Apps that fundamentally do the following:

On a time trigger, a set of SQL stored procedures are called, then a series of Select Statements are run, These are piped to a CSV table which is then emailed to the report recipients.

The process works fine with one issue - A number of the columns in SQL have spaces in them.

When I run a `select [column 1] from table` in SQL, it works correctly.

When I run the same select from within Logic Apps - the output has been modified to I believe URI encoding Example:

```
Column_x0020_1  
result1  
result2  
result3  
etc.
```

When I run a debug, I see that this is generated on the output of the Execute SQL Query, not on the creation of the CSV table and I don't see any option to either escape the spaces so that they  don't encode in the URI format or something to programagically change the URI encoded column names/data to 'normal' encoding.

So please, help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below expression to convert the column name with URI encoding to normal format

```
 replace(string(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')),'_x0020_',' ')
```

Here is the sample output for reference

[image]

[image]

- Used compose to remove the URI encoded column name to normal name

[image]

**updating the logic app code:**

```html
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(replace(string(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)')),'_x0020_',' '))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@variables('array')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "query": "select [column 1] from [dbo].[test]"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/query/sql"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "array",
                            "value": "@body('Parse_JSON')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['ResultSets']?['Table1']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "array",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "OutputParameters": {
                                "properties": {},
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "ResultSets": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "Table1": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "column 1": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "column 1"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "sql_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource gourp >/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-9",
                    "connectionName": "sql-9",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/northcentralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Refence Q&A article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/201003/logic-apps-authentication-error.html)

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble configuring this - can you clarify which data operations the replace(...) is defined in?

Also, when I tested this, trying to output it to a CSV is now failing saying it's a String and not an Array

Comment: @TheDemonLord - updated the answer with logic code view & additional screenshots.

Comment: Thanks! That should give me all I need